# Window functions: PARTITION BY one column after ORDER BY another

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

**Disclaimer:** The shown problem is much more general than I expected first. The example below is taken from a solution to another question. But now I was taking this sample for solving many problems more - mostly related to time series (have a look at the "Linked" section in the right bar).

So I am trying to explain the problem more generally first:

---

*I am using PostgreSQL but I am sure this problem exists in other window function supporting DBMS' (MS SQL Server, Oracle, ...) as well.*

---

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) can be used to group certain values together by a common attribute or value. For example you can group rows by a date. Then you are able to calculate the max value within every single date or an average value or counting rows or whatever.

This can be achieved by defining a `PARTITION`. Grouping by dates would work with `PARTITION BY date_column`. Now you want to do an operation which needs a special order within your groups (calculating row numbers or sum up a column). This can be done with `PARTITON BY date_column ORDER BY an_attribute_column`.

Now think about a finer resolution of time series. What if you do not have dates but timestamps. Then you cannot group by the time column anymore. But nevertheless it might be important to analyse the data in the order they were added (maybe the timestamp is the creating time of your data set). Then you realize that some consecutive rows have the same value and you want to group your data by this common value. But the clue is that the rows have different timestamps.

The problem here is that you cannot do a `PARTITION BY value_column`. Because `PARTITION BY` forces an ordering first. So your table would be ordered by the `value_column` before the grouping and is not ordered by the timestamp anymore. This yields in results you are not expecting.

More general speaking: **The problem is to ensure a special ordering even if the ordered column is not part of the created partition**.

---

**Example:**

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bdc19b179565066afe2869dc61a43343)

I have the following table:

```
ts      val
100000  50
130100  30050
160100  60050 
190200  100
220200  30100 
250200  30100 
300000  300
500000  100
550000  1000  
600000  1000
650000  2000  
700000  2000
720000  2000
750000  300
```

I had the problem that I had to group all tied values of the column `val`. But I wanted to hold the order by `ts`. To achieve this I wanted to add a column with a unique ID per `val` group

**Expected result:**

```
ts      val     group
100000  50      1
130100  30050   2
160100  60050   3
190200  100     4
220200  30100   5     \ same group
250200  30100   5     /
300000  300     6
500000  100     7
550000  1000    8     \ same group
600000  1000    8     /
650000  2000    9     \
700000  2000    9     | same group
720000  2000    9     /
750000  300     10
```

**First try** was the use of the `rank` window function which would do this job normally:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY ts)
FROM 
    test
```

But in this case this doesn't work because the `PARTITION BY` clause orders the table first by its partition columns (`val` in this case) and then by its `ORDER BY` columns. So the order is by `val, ts` instead of the expected order by `ts`. So the result was not the expected one of course.

```
ts       val     rank
100000   50      1
190200   100     1
500000   100     2
300000   300     1
750000   300     2
550000   1000    1
600000   1000    2
650000   2000    1
700000   2000    2
720000   2000    3
130100   30050   1
220200   30100   1
250200   30100   2
160100   60050   1
```

The question is: **How to get the group ids with respect to the order by `ts`**?

---

**Edit:** I added an own solution below but I feel very uncomfortable with it. It seems way too complicated. **I was wondering if there's a better way** to achieve this result.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm old.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with this solution by myself (**hoping someone else will get a better one**):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=03f126fb36b799f5e355d79cde538068)

1. order by `ts`
2. give out the next `val` value with the `lag` window function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)
3. check if the next and the current values are the same. Then I can print out a `0` or a `1`
4. sum up these values with an ordered `SUM`. This generates the groups I am looking for. They group the `val` column but ensure the ordering by the `ts` column.

**The query:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(is_diff) OVER (ORDER BY ts) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN val = lag(val) over (order by ts) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as is_diff
    FROM test 
)s
```

**The result:**

```
ts       val     is_diff   sum
100000   50      1         1
130100   30050   1         2
160100   60050   1         3
190200   100     1         4
220200   30100   1         5    \ group
250200   30100   0         5    /
300000   300     1         6
500000   100     1         7
550000   1000    1         8    \ group
600000   1000    0         8    /
650000   2000    1         9    \
700000   2000    0         9    | group
720000   2000    0         9    /
750000   300     1         10
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that, it didn't occur to me to use rolling sum for making groups like that. Also, depending on RDBMS you can get rid of subquery by applying sum directly over case-lag, like `SUM(CASE WHEN val = lag(val) over (order by ts) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ts)`

Comment: Hi, well, at least in Postgres this does not work because "window function call cannot be nested"

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76424422/3984221) answer is a solution for a quite similar problem and therefore led me to another way. This is a kind of the gaps-and-islands problem and so can be solved as one:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ts) 
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY ts) as grp
FROM test
ORDER BY ts
```

This is how the result looks like:

```
ts      val     grp
100000  50      0
130100  30050   1
160100  60050   2
190200  100     3
220200  30100   4     \ group
250200  30100   4     /
300000  300     6     
500000  100     6
550000  1000    8     \ group
600000  1000    8     /
650000  2000    10    \
700000  2000    10    | group
720000  2000    10    /
750000  300     12
```

1. It can happen that some group IDs exist several times (here you can see ID `#6` as an example). This is fine, because the group ID is unique in combination with the value column. So, if you wanted to get pure unique IDs, this approach will not work properly. But as group with the value column it becomes unique.
2. It's not a consecutive number of IDs; and even worse: The numbers may not constantly increasing as this example shows:

   ```
    ts      val     grp
    100000  50      0
    130100  30050   1
    160100  60050   2
    190200  100     3
    220200  30100   4
    250200  30100   4
    300000  300     6
    310000  30100   5  -- added an extra record here
    500000  100     7
    550000  1000    9
    600000  1000    9
    650000  2000    11
    700000  2000    11
    720000  2000    11
    750000  300     13
   ```

In the end you will get a classification of the value column with unique IDs for same values in different groups, which is the main goal of the question. This can be ordered by the sort order column afterwards. The result is not as comfortable as the [`lag`/`sum` window solution I presented first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52439794/3984221), but:

1. Works with a more commonly known algorithm called "gaps and islands" and, therefore, could be more readable and understandable.
2. Works with no additional subquery