# Min and max of grouped time sequences in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a large Postgres table `test` from which I would like to extract **consecutive** sequences of `no_signal` states per `mobile_id`, or in other words the length of time individual mobile devices go out of service.

In the real table, records are not ordered, which I think would mean a `PARTITION OVER (time, mobile_id`) statement would have to be included, in addition to a window function.  Any advice on how to create a group for individual consecutive sequences, and then to take the min and max per group would be appreciated.

```
-- CREATE TABLE test (mobile_id int, state varchar, time timestamp, region varchar)

INSERT INTO test (mobile_id, state, time, region ) VALUES
(1, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 15:00:00', 'EU'),  
(1, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 16:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 17:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 18:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 19:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 20:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'inactive', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 21:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 22:00:00', 'EU'),
(1, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-09 23:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 00:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 01:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 02:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 03:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 04:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 05:00:00', 'EU'),
(2, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 06:00:00', 'EU'),
(3, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 07:00:00', 'SA'),
(3, 'active', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 08:00:00', 'SA'),
(3, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 09:00:00', 'SA'),
(3, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 10:00:00', 'SA'),
(3, 'inactive', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 11:00:00', 'SA'),
(3, 'inactive', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 12:00:00', 'SA'),
(3, 'no_signal', TIMESTAMP '2018-08-10 13:00:00', 'SA')
```

The output that I am aiming for would be something like this:

```
 mobile_id          start_time            end_time diff_time region
         1 2018-08-09 17:00:00 2018-08-09 19:00:00       120     EU
         2 2018-08-10 01:00:00 2018-08-10 01:00:00         0     EU
         2 2018-08-10 03:00:00 2018-08-10 06:00:00       180     EU
         3 2018-08-10 09:00:00 2018-08-10 10:00:00        60     SA
         3 2018-08-10 13:00:00 2018-08-10 13:00:00         0     SA
```

The following code does not produce the desired result as groups are not correctly created:

```
select mobile_id, region,
       least(extract(epoch from max(time) - min(time)), 0) as diff
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where state = 'no_signal) over (partition by mobile_id, region order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by mobile_id, region, grp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the gaps and island problem.  In this case, you are trying to detect multiple islands of records having `no_signal` for each mobile number.

This answer uses the "difference in row number method."  The trick has to do with applying `ROW_NUMBER` over your table in two ways.  The first one generates the sequence over all records, ordered by time, while the second generates the sequence for each `mobile_id` group, and then only for those records whose status is `no_signal`.  The *difference* in these row number values can be used to form each of the islands.  Then, we only need to aggregate and take the min/max timestamp value to get the result you want.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) rn1
    FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mobile_id ORDER BY time) rn2
    FROM test
    WHERE state = 'no_signal'
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT t1.*, t2.rn2
    FROM cte1 t1
    LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
        ON t1.mobile_id = t2.mobile_id AND t1.time = t2.time
    WHERE t1.state = 'no_signal'
)

SELECT
    mobile_id,
    MIN(time) AS start_time,
    MAX(time) AS end_time,
    EXTRACT(epoch FROM MAX(time::timestamp) - MIN(time::timestamp)) / 60 diff_time,
    region
FROM cte3
GROUP BY
    mobile_id,
    region,
    (rn1 - rn2)
ORDER BY
    mobile_id,
    start_time;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=390b19ad7437521a57a1067c4def1558)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    mobile_id,
    first_value(time) over (partition by ranked, time) as start_time,        -- B
    first_value(time) over (partition by ranked, time desc) as end_time, 
    region
FROM
(
    SELECT *, SUM(is_diff) OVER (ORDER BY time) as ranked                          -- A
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
            CASE WHEN state = lag(state) over (order by time) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as is_diff
        FROM test 
    ) s
) s
WHERE
    state = 'no_signal';
```

A: The problem is that you are trying to order a column and then you want to do a partition for another. This problem can be solved by this subquery. The problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319688/postgresql-window-functions-rank-by-one-column-after-order-by-another). I am searching for a better solution but this subquery works. This creates a column which can be used for your wanted window.

B: After creating the window your `start_time` and `end_time` can be calculated easily by using the `first_value(time)` and `first_value(time) ... ORDER BY time DESC` function. `DESC` because it sorts the window with the latest time and then you can get the first value of that ([`last_value()` does not work as expected every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299101/window-function-last-valueorder-by-asc-same-as-last-valueorder-by-de)).

---

For more clearness to the real problem I left out the `diff` calculation above: To add the `diff` you only need to do a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *,  
    EXTRACT(epoch from (end_time - start_time)) / 60 as diff
FROM (
    -- <QUERY ABOVE>
) s
```