# PostgreSQL row_number( ) window function starting counter from 1 for each change

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

Can't find a way to implement a specific row_number() function in Postgres. See the table below:

[table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRw6M.png)

I want from row_number to start counter from one for each difference like for items a and c. Third column is what I want.

my code:

`select item, flag, row_number() over (partition by item, flag order by item) as rownum from t`

| item | flag | day | row_number_current | row_number_required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| a | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| a | 1 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| a | 0 | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 7 | 4 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 8 | 5 | 2 |
| b | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| b | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| c | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| c | 0 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| c | 1 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| c | 1 | 7 | 5 | 3 |

Comment: Please show data as (formatted) text, not as (link to) image. Your data doesn't seem to have any order

Comment: What is logic so that in line 6, you want `a-0-3` become `a-0-1`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger added table

Comment: @PhamX.Bach yes, exactly

Comment: You are showing the rows in a particular order, and this order seems to be important for you. Is there a column to determine that order? An ID or a date column? Then please add it to your data example. If there is no such column, then there just is no order and your results will be arbitrary, because data in a database table is an unordered data set by definition.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i think it's not crucial, but I added day column as example

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f00686ad3055cca58db886979feb7fbc)

It's the same problem, I discussed in detail here:

[Window functions: PARTITION BY one column after ORDER BY another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319688/window-functions-partition-by-one-column-after-order-by-another)

You are trying to create partitions by two columns, but try to keep the order indicated by a third. Problem is that a `PARTITION BY` clause internally orders before the partition is created. So you need to introduce an identifier which keeps the order.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(is_diff) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day) -- 2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE                                           -- 1
            WHEN flag = lag(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day) 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END as is_diff
    FROM mytable 
)s
```

1. Check if the next value equals the current value. If not, make it `1` (indicates a value change), else `0` (no value change).
2. Cumulative sum: Each `1` increases the value, each `0` keeps the previous. This yields a new group id beginning at each `1`. This is exactly the result you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks!!!

Finally found a way to calculate row number, but I had to add one more row_number function on top of your sum in order numerate flag=1 rows