# Need to add sequential numbering as per the grouping in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, row-number

I am working on one code where I need to add sequential number as per the grouping on the basis of column A & column B. Below is the table/dataframe I have. The data is sorted by colA & Date.

| colA | colB | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 01-01-2014 |
| A | 1 | 01-02-2014 |
| A | 3 | 30-04-2014 |
| A | 3 | 05-05-2014 |
| A | 2 | 25-05-2014 |
| A | 1 | 06-06-2014 |
| A | 1 | 21-07-2014 |
| B | 1 | 04-09-2014 |
| B | 1 | 19-10-2014 |
| B | 1 | 03-12-2014 |
| C | 3 | 17-01-2015 |
| C | 2 | 03-03-2015 |
| C | 2 | 17-04-2015 |

Following is the expected result:

| colA | colB | Date | ROWNUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 01-01-2014 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 01-02-2014 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 30-04-2014 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 05-05-2014 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 25-05-2014 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 06-06-2014 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 21-07-2014 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 04-09-2014 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 19-10-2014 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 03-12-2014 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 17-01-2015 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 03-03-2015 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 17-04-2015 | 2 |

I am trying to use row_number here and getting the below result where for A(colA) the next occurrence of 1(colB) has rownumber added as 3 instead of 1:

| colA | colB | Date | ROWNUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 01-01-2014 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 01-02-2014 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 30-04-2014 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 05-05-2014 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 25-05-2014 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 06-06-2014 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 21-07-2014 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 04-09-2014 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 19-10-2014 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 03-12-2014 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 17-01-2015 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 03-03-2015 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 17-04-2015 | 2 |

Comment: Hi I added my answer, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please edit the question to add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
w=Window.orderBy(F.asc("colA"), F.asc("Date"))

df\
.withColumn("eq", F.when(F.lag("colB").over(w)==F.col("colB"), 0).otherwise(1))\
.withColumn("groups", F.sum("eq").over(w))\
.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(w.partitionBy(F.col("colA"), F.col("groups"))))\
.show()
```

Thanks to this answer: [Window functions: PARTITION BY one column after ORDER BY another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319688/window-functions-partition-by-one-column-after-order-by-another)

Input:

```
+----+----+----------+
|colA|colB|      Date|
+----+----+----------+
|   A|   1|2014-01-01|
|   A|   1|2014-02-01|
|   A|   3|2014-04-30|
|   A|   3|2014-05-05|
|   A|   2|2014-05-25|
|   A|   1|2014-06-06|
|   A|   1|2014-07-21|
|   B|   1|2014-09-04|
|   B|   1|2014-10-19|
|   B|   1|2014-12-03|
|   C|   3|2015-01-17|
|   C|   2|2015-03-03|
|   C|   2|2015-04-17|
+----+----+----------+
```

Output (Keeping the intermediate columns for understanding, you can drop them):

```
+----+----+----------+---+------+-------+
|colA|colB|      Date| eq|groups|row_num|
+----+----+----------+---+------+-------+
|   A|   1|2014-01-01|  1|     1|      1|
|   A|   1|2014-02-01|  0|     1|      2|
|   A|   3|2014-04-30|  1|     2|      1|
|   A|   3|2014-05-05|  0|     2|      2|
|   A|   2|2014-05-25|  1|     3|      1|
|   A|   1|2014-06-06|  1|     4|      1|
|   A|   1|2014-07-21|  0|     4|      2|
|   B|   1|2014-09-04|  0|     4|      1|
|   B|   1|2014-10-19|  0|     4|      2|
|   B|   1|2014-12-03|  0|     4|      3|
|   C|   3|2015-01-17|  1|     5|      1|
|   C|   2|2015-03-03|  1|     6|      1|
|   C|   2|2015-04-17|  0|     6|      2|
+----+----+----------+---+------+-------+
```

Comment: This has worked Ronak. Thanks a lot :)