# Get the maximum consecutive count of a name in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I was asked this question in a job interview:

[image]

There is a table with vehicle names mentioned in a column. Output when we check for name=car we must get as 4 i.e the maximum count of continuous occurrence of 'car' in the column.

Can somebody help me get this solution in PostgreSQL?

I tried using rank and dense rank but it didn't work.

Comment: How do you define consecutive occurrences? SQL tables are intrinsically unordered, so unless there's some other column you can order by (e.g., a timestamp), calling entries "consecutive" is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** As already stated by @Mureinik in the comments: This can only work if there is a dedicated column for ordering (e.g. an increasing ID or a timestamp). The reason is, that in the database the column order is not determined. So you always need a sort order criterion if you'd deal with specific orders. In the example below I added an `id` column.

---

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mW_gWWzf)

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)                        -- 2
FROM (
    SELECT                                                       -- 1
        *,
        SUM(eq) OVER (ORDER BY id) as group_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            (name != lag(name) OVER (ORDER BY id))::int as eq
        FROM mytable
    ) s
) s
ORDER BY count DESC                                              -- 3
LIMIT 1                                                          -- 4
```

1. First part is similar to what I already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319688/window-functions-partition-by-one-column-after-order-by-another), for example. You can find this in the subqueries. It is about [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) partitioning while keeping the original sort order. It creates unique group ids for each specific `name` group.
2. Using `COUNT()` window function to count the records of each group.
3. Afterwards order the biggest count first.
4. Return only the first record (which contains the highest count number)

Comment: @ManojPr Solving solutions should be marked as solved (the check mark beside the correct solution)

Comment: Hi @S-Man I am pretty new to this so didn't know about it. I have done it now. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

This is a gaps and islands problem, you could try the difference between two row numbers to solve it.

This can be done only if there is a column you can order by (e.g. an increasing ID or a timestamp) as mentioned by @Mureinik and @S-Man :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
    *, row_number() over(order by id) - row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as grp
  FROM mytable
)
select name, count(1)
from cte
where name = 'car' 
group by name, grp
order by count(1) desc
limit 1
```

To get the maximum count of continuous occurrence for all names, just remove the `where` clause

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/a85blZzi)

Comment: The OP is asking that if we check for name = 'car' we have to get 4 !

Comment: Ok, you are right, sorry :) I thought, he wanted to get the column with the highest count independent of the name.